# SUDS python connection

Tags: python, suds

im trying to build an client for an webservice in python with suds. i used the tutorial
on this site: http://www.jansipke.nl/python-soap-client-with-suds. Its working with my own written Webservice and WSDL, but not with the wsdl file i got. The wsdl file is working in soapUI, i can send requests and get an answer. So the problem is, i think, how suds is parsing the wsdl file. I get following error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Any ideas how to fix that? If you need more information please ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you have given us seems to imply that the URL you are using to access the WSDL is not correct.  could you show us a bit more of your code? for example the client instatiation and the url to the WSDL.  this might allow others to actually help you.

Olly

Answer (score 1):

```
# SUDS is primarily built for Python 2.6/7 (Lightweight SOAP client)
# SUDS does not work properly with other version, absolutely no support for 3.x
# Test your code with Python 2.7.12 (I am using)

from suds.client import Client
from suds.sax.text import Raw

# Use your tested URL same format with '?wsdl', Check once in SOAP-UI, below is dummy
# Make sure to use same Method name in below function 'client.service.MethodName'
url = 'http://localhost:8080/your/path/MethodName?wsdl'

#Use your Request XML, below is dummy, format xml=Raw('xml_text')
xml = Raw('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:diag=" </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>') 

def GetResCode(url, xml):
    client = Client(url)
    xml_response = (client.service.MethodName(__inject={'msg':xml}))
    return xml_response

print(GetResCode(url,xml))
```